# Variants of Bernoulli factory problems

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

I am interested in the following two questions related to the famous Bernoulli factory problems.

1. Bernoulli factory for certain functions: suppose we are given a coin with arbitrary (unknown) head probability $p$, I am wondering if there is an easy-to-implement algorithm for generating a $\min\{p, 0.5\}$ coin for any $p\in [0,1]$. Function $f(p) = \min\{p, 0.5\} \geq \min\{p, 1-p\}$ so the famous paper by  [Keane and O’Brien](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/175007.175019) guarantees such an algorithm exists. Meanwhile, the function looks slightly simpler than the function discussed in [Nacu and Peres](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1106922322), so I am wondering if there is any existing simple algorithm for simulating this. Similarly, can we simulate $f(p) = \min\{p,a\}$ for fixed $a\in (0,1)$ efficiently?
2. High dimensional Bernoulli factory: How to simulate a coin with head probability $f(p_1, p_2)$ (for example $f(p_1, p_2) = \min\{p_1, p_2, 0.5\}$), or more generally, simulating a coin with head probability $f(p_1, \cdots, p_n)$. The setting here is that we are able so simulate a $p_i$ coin, but without further knowledge on the value of $p_i$, which is consistent with the traditional Bernoulli factory's setting.  When $f$ is a single variable function then the problem is reduced to the Bernoulli factory problem.

Any reference/idea will be much appreciated for the multivariate case, thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/493731/8030 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/494302/8030. (A comment at the first link points out that your (1) above has negative answer when *efficiency* is required.)

Answer (score 3):

I reproduce my answers from *Cross Validated*:

On number 1:

Since the function min(*λ*, *c*) meets the Keane–O'Brien theorem, this implies that there are polynomials that converge from above and below to the function. This is discussed, for example, in Thomas and Blanchet (2012) and in Łatuszyński et al. (2009/2011). However, neither paper shows how to automate the task of finding polynomials required for the method to work, so that finding such a sequence for an arbitrary function (that satisfies the Keane–O'Brien theorem) remains far from trivial (and [the question interests me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904732/what-are-ways-to-compute-polynomials-that-converge-from-above-and-below-to-a-con) to some extent, too).

But fortunately, there is an alternative way to simulate min(*λ*, 1/2) without having to build a sequence of polynomials explicitly. This algorithm I found is given below, and I have a [**page**](https://peteroupc.github.io/morealg.html#Derivation_of_My_Algorithm_for_min___lambda___1_2) describing the derivation of this algorithm.

1. With probability 1/2, flip the input coin and return the result.
2. (Random walk.) Generate unbiased random bits until more zeros than ones are generated this way for the first time. Then set *m* to (*n* −1)/2+1, where *n* is the number of bits generated this way.
3. (Build a degree-*m**2 polynomial equivalent to (4**λ**(1− *λ* ))<sup>*m*</sup>/2.) Let *z* be (4<sup>*m*</sup>/2)/choose(*m**2, *m*). Define a polynomial of degree *m**2 whose (*m**2)+1 Bernstein coefficients are all zero except the *m*<sup>th</sup> coefficient (starting at 0), whose value is *z*. Elevate the degree of this polynomial enough times so that all its coefficients are 1 or less. Let *d* be the new polynomial's degree.
4. (Simulate the polynomial, whose degree is *d* (Goyal and Sigman 2012).) Flip the input coin *d* times and set *h* to the number of ones generated this way. Let *a* be the *h*<sup>th</sup> Bernstein coefficient (starting at 0) of the new polynomial. With probability *a*, return 1. Otherwise, return 0.

I suspected that the required degree *d* would be floor(*m**2/3)+1. With help from the [**MathOverflow community**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381419), steps 3 and 4 of the algorithm can be described more efficiently as follows:

- (3.) Let *r* be floor(*m**2/3)+1, and let *d* be *m**2+*r*.
- (4.) (Simulate the polynomial, whose degree is *d*.) Flip the input coin *d* times and set *h* to the number of ones generated this way. Let *a* be (1/2) * 2<sup>*m**2</sup>*choose(*r*, *h* − *m*)/choose(*d*, *h*) (the polynomial's *h*<sup>th</sup> Bernstein coefficient starting at 0; the first term is 1/2 because the polynomial being simulated has the value 1/2 at the point 1/2). With probability *a*, return 1. Otherwise, return 0. (Here, choose(*n*, *k*) is a binomial coefficient.)

In addition, there is an approximate way to sample min(*λ*, *c*) and most other continuous functions *f* that map (0, 1) to (0, 1). Specifically, it's trivial to simulate an individual polynomial with Bernstein coefficients in [0, 1], even if the polynomial has high degree and follows the desired function closely (Goyal and Sigman 2012):

- Flip the input coin *n* times (where *n* is the polynomial's degree), and let *j* be the number of ones.
- With probability *a*[*j*], that is, the j-th control point, starting at 0, for the polynomial's corresponding Bézier curve, return 1. Otherwise, return 0.

To use this algorithm, simply calculate *a*[*j*] = *f*(*j*/*n*), where *n* is the desired degree of the polynomial (such as 100). Each *a*[*j*] is one of the Bernstein coefficients of a polynomial that closely approximates the function; the higher *n* is, the better the approximation.

On number 2:

A related problem is the *Dice Enterprise* problem first given by Morina et al. 2019/2020, which involves simulating a *m*-faced die with a *n*-faced die, where the faces have separate probabilities of occurring. This is not the same as the problem in your question, though, as these probabilities are interrelated rather than independent.

REFERENCES:

- Goyal, V. And Sigman, K., 2012. On simulating a class of Bernstein polynomials. ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation (TOMACS), 22(2), pp.1-5.
- Łatuszyński, K., Kosmidis, I., Papaspiliopoulos, O., Roberts, G.O., "Simulating events of unknown probabilities via reverse time martingales", arXiv:0907.4018v2 [stat.CO], 2009/2011.
- Morina, G., Łatuszyński, K., et al., "[From the Bernoulli Factory to a Dice Enterprise via Perfect Sampling of Markov Chains](http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09229v2)", arXiv:1912.09229 [math.PR], 2019/2020.

---

EDIT (Nov. 13):

A very relevant paper was just made available and came to my attention:

Niazadeh, R., Leme, R.P., Schneider, J., "[Combinatorial Bernoulli Factories: Matchings, Flows, and Polytopes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.03865.pdf)", arXiv:2011.03865v1 [cs.DS], Nov. 7, 2020.

(Edited Apr. 4):

Let $f:\mathcal{P}\to [0, 1]$ be a function.

In the traditional Bernoulli factory problem, we have a coin with unknown probability of heads $\lambda$ and we seek to sample the probability $f(\lambda)$. In this case, the domain $\mathcal{P}$ is either $[0, 1]$ or a subset thereof.

The paper cited above, however, studies Bernoulli factories when $f$ has a different domain: namely when $\mathcal{P}$ is a "polytope contained in the unit hypercube", that is, either $[0,1]^n$ or a subset thereof. Now the Bernoulli factory problem is as follows:

- Define a polytope $\mathcal{P}$ as above.
- We have $n$ coins with unknown probabilities of heads of $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$. These probabilities form a vector $x = (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ lying on inside the polytope.
- Assign a specially-designed coin to each vertex of $\mathcal{P}$.
- Sample a vertex (coin) of the polytope such that the expected value equals $x$.

For example, given two coins the vector is $x = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$, and one possible choice of $\mathcal{P}$ is $[0, 1]\times[0, 1]$. In that case, there are four vertices, namely $(0, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(1, 1)$. When this procedure is done enough times, the sampled vertices average to $x$.

The main question studied in this paper is *whether and how* a polytope of the kind just given admits a Bernoulli factory.

Unfortunately, this is a different problem from the Bernoulli factory problem you give in your question, where the goal is to sample the probability $f((\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n))$ given $n$ coins each with unknown probability of heads of $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ as the case may be. Moreover, the use of the term "Bernoulli factory" as studied in the paper may be misleading, because the output of the algorithm is not necessarily a Bernoulli random variable. (This is so even though the paper defines "one-bit Bernoulli factories" similarly to traditional Bernoulli factories.) As a result, the paper didn't study any conditions on $f$ that are necessary for a Bernoulli factory of the kind you give in your question, such as whether $f$ has to be continuous or bounded away from its domain.

---

Nacu & Peres found algorithms to solve the Bernoulli factory problem using approximation theory. Currently, polynomials and rational functions are the main kinds of multivariate functions I am aware of that have Bernoulli factory algorithms (Morina et al.) Many multivariate analytic functions are also taken care of by the composition rule (e.g., proposition 14(ii) of Nacu and Peres).

However, although the function $g = \min(\lambda_0, \lambda_1)$ is continuous, it's not differentiable, which presents an apparent difficulty.

But by the Stone--Weierstrass theorem, any continuous function on $[0, 1]^d$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by polynomials, so I suspect the following:

- The necessary conditions of Keane and O'Brien extend to multivariate functions: the function must be continuous on $[0, 1]^d$ and either constant or polynomially bounded, which seems to be the case for $g$. I also suspect that similarly to the proof of Keane and O'Brien, any such function $f$ can be simulated by finding multivariate, continuous and polynomially bounded functions $f_k$ that approximate $f$ from below, although the algorithm in that proof is far from practical as it requires finding the degree of approximation for each function $f_k$.
- Since an approximate polynomial exists for any such continuous function, the algorithm for simulating polynomials given by Goyal and Sigman can be easily extended to the multivariate case: flip each coin n times, count the number of heads for each coin, then return 0 with probability equal to the chosen monomial's coefficient.
- There may be an algorithm that works similarly in the multivariate case to the [general Bernoulli factory algorithms](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html#General_Factory_Functions) in the univariate case, including the one by Nacu & Peres.

This will require looking at the research on multivariate polynomial approximation (especially research that gives bounds on the approximation error with polynomials, especially multivariate polynomials in Bernstein form).

It's also possible that for the particular function $g$, a series expansion exists whose terms can be "tucked" under a discrete probability mass function, which enables an algorithm to simulate $g$ via convex combinations (Wästlund 1999, Theorem 2.7), as is the case for $\min(\lambda, 1/2)$, [for example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/495906/296678).

EDIT (Sep. 28, 2021): Also, see chapter 3 of G. Morina's doctoral dissertation (2021), which shows that multivariate Bernoulli factories require the function to be continuous and polynomially bounded.

EDIT (Feb. 18, 2022):  A new paper by Leme and Schneider (2022), "[Multiparameter Bernoulli Factories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.07216.pdf)", deals with the problem you're asking about.  Among other things, they show that a function $f(p_1, ..., p_n)$ admits a Bernoulli factory if and only if $f$ is continuous and meets a polynomial boundedness condition that reduces in the 1-dimensional case to that found in Keane and O'Brien.

REFERENCES:

- Goyal, V. And Sigman, K., 2012. On simulating a class of Bernstein polynomials. ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation (TOMACS), 22(2), pp.1-5.
- Wästlund, J., "[Functions arising by coin flipping](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ewastlund/coinFlip.pdf)", 1999.
- Morina, Giulio (2021) Extending the Bernoulli Factory to a dice enterprise. PhD thesis, University of Warwick.

Comment: thanks a lot! It's super helpful!